# new pc..noisy fan

Tags: fan

It's a new build, but it's always had noisy fans. From start to end, they will not stop running.  The case is a cooler master which I believe comes with a fan that is not controlled by BIOS (according to technician), so that may be the source of the problem..but my lack of knowledge on the matter prevents me from making a reasonable assessment. Here are readings from CoreTemp:

Model: Intel Core i7 870 (Lynnfield)

Platform: LAG 1156 (Socket H)

Frequency: 1658.23MHz (132.66 x 12.5)

Tj. Max: 99 C

Core #0: low= 34 C; high= 42 C; Load= 0%

Core #1: low 31 C; high 42 C; load= 0%

Core #3: 35 C; 42 C; 0%

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a high-end graphics card fitted?

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce 210

Answer (score 2):

You did not include any information on how fast the case and CPU cooler fans are spinning, which is information that is usually available in the BIOS, and also available from software that you can run while in the operating system, whatever that may be.

Fans usually get very noisy at around 1800+ RPM, IIRC, and very quiet when just about 1000 RPM.  The BIOS usually alerts a fan as failing if it goes below 1000 RPM.

Slower, but larger fans can move as much air as faster, smaller ones.  It's best to use 120mm case fans that run at around 1200 RPM.  Some models are quieter than others, even at the same speed.  Websites like [silentpcreview.com](http://www.silentpcreview.com/section12.html) and [quietpc.com](http://www.quietpc.com/us-en-usd/products/casefans) (commercial) may help you find out more.

You can also get [in-line resistors](http://www.quietpc.com/us-en-usd/products/casefanaccessories/resistors) and [potentiometers](http://www.quietpc.com/us-en-usd/products/casefanaccessories/fanmate2) that can slow down the fans you have already, but buying more efficient, larger and slower fans is better.

You can get quiet CPU coolers and PSUs as well.  I always build my machines to be as quiet as reasonably possible.

Comment: SYSFAN  1222 RPM  1196 RPM  1231 RPM

Comment: CPUFANIN0   2220 RPM   2163 RPM   2220 RPM

Comment: AUXFANIN0   1147 RPM   1140 RPM   1180 RPM

Comment: *These are readings from HWMonitorPro

Comment: @BRQ: It looks like you already have 120mm case fans, judging by the slow speeds. Your CPU cooler is probably making the most noise. See if there is a BIOS option to control it. You may need to replace it. It is possible that the most noise is coming from your graphics card cooler or PSU. You can try putting your finger on the centre of the CPU fan to make it stop, to hear if it was the loudest thing.

Comment: with the computer on?

Comment: @BRQ: Yes, but whether this is practical, safe or possible depends on what sort of cooler you have.  If you can see the hub in the middle, you can use the pad of a finger to slow it down and then stop it from spinning for a few seconds.  This is just to see if it is the noisy component.

Answer (score 0):

If the room is properly cooled you can try disconnecting the fan which is making sound.

Keeping something heavy on cabinet reduces sound as vibration would reduce significantly. The heavier the load, the better is the reduction in sound.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Cooler Master fans always have three-pin connectors, so you could plug them into the motherboard if the connectors are there - that should reduce noise.

Other than that, there's probably not much else you can do without getting new fans, and maybe a new CPU cooler (if yours is stock). If you really want to reduce noise, you can get soundproofing insulation for your case - I've never tried this myself, though.

If your problem involves vibration, you could also try placing rubber where the fans contact the case - this won't help if it's just fan noise, though.

Comment: when i went to pick it up, the tech allowed me to listen for myself and I found that the noise level was reduced exponentially. in my home set-up the case is enclosed by 1/2 inch-thick wood with about an inch of space between the left and right sides of the case and the desk. the front is not blocked by anything, and the back is ~4-5 inches from the wall. what's good about this case is that there's one (of 3) fan in the back, so there's airflow front to back. it could be that it's just not enough space. what do you think? although i my older desktop didn't make much noise.

Answer (score 0):

I find the CPU fan is almost always the noisiest. Make sure to clean the CPU and CPU fan with a can of compressed "air". If the CPU/Fan is dirty, the MB will continually increase the CPU fan speed (faster and faster) in an effort to keep the CPU temperature down. If it is dirty and you clean it, you will immediately notice the fan running slower and quieter.

Depending on the heat sink design you may not even think it is dirty since the dirt may be accumulated deeper in the heat sink, so it is a good idea to try to clean it in any case.